# Issue installing Arjun in kali linux due to python distro-package issues

Tags: python, setuptools

I have issues installing Arjun, as i get error messages about setup issues in some python libraries distro-packages. Any help on this issue will be highly appreciated. Incase you might ask, i have done upgrade and update already.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/armes/Tools/Arjun/setup.py", line 11, in <module>
    setup(
  File "/home/armes/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 106, in setup
    _install_setup_requires(attrs)
  File "/home/armes/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 74, in _install_setup_requires
    dist = MinimalDistribution(attrs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/armes/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 56, in __init__
    super().__init__(filtered)
  File "/home/armes/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 484, in __init__
    for ep in metadata.entry_points(group='distutils.setup_keywords'):
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 1040, in entry_points
    return SelectableGroups.load(eps).select(**params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 476, in load
    ordered = sorted(eps, key=by_group)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 1037, in <genexpr>
    eps = itertools.chain.from_iterable(
                                       ^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/importlib/metadata/_itertools.py", line 16, in unique_everseen
    k = key(element)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 954, in _normalized_name
    or super()._normalized_name
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 627, in _normalized_name
    return Prepared.normalize(self.name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 882, in normalize
    return re.sub(r"[-_.]+", "-", name).lower().replace('-', '_')
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/re/__init__.py", line 185, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object, got 'NoneType'
```

I have issues installing Arjun(an HTTP parameter fuzzing tool) in kali linux,i have run apt-get updates and upgrade. Also ran dist-upgrade. Is there any solution to this problem? This is the error code i get when i install setup.py for the tool.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/armes/Tools/Arjun/setup.py", line 11, in <module>
    setup(
  File "/home/armes/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 106, in setup
    _install_setup_requires(attrs)
  File "/home/armes/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 74, in _install_setup_requires
    dist = MinimalDistribution(attrs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/armes/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 56, in __init__
    super().__init__(filtered)
  File "/home/armes/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 484, in __init__
    for ep in metadata.entry_points(group='distutils.setup_keywords'):
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 1040, in entry_points
    return SelectableGroups.load(eps).select(**params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 476, in load
    ordered = sorted(eps, key=by_group)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 1037, in <genexpr>
    eps = itertools.chain.from_iterable(
                                       ^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/importlib/metadata/_itertools.py", line 16, in unique_everseen
    k = key(element)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 954, in _normalized_name
    or super()._normalized_name
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 627, in _normalized_name
    return Prepared.normalize(self.name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 882, in normalize
    return re.sub(r"[-_.]+", "-", name).lower().replace('-', '_')
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/re/__init__.py", line 185, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object, got 'NoneType'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your traceback refers to packages in `/usr/lib` and `~/.local/lib`, so your local python environment accesses ressources from system's python, which is a recipe for disaster. I recommend installing `pyenv` and starting over from a clean virtualenv.